# How to open and setup a timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to plot a timeseries graph but it shows an error like this:

> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (180,) and
> (179,)

This is the script I use to open the data and setup the date range:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/chris/Downloads/UNDIP/Organisasi/Algomarine/Workshop/ONI/Indeks.xls')
Waktu = date_range(start='01/01/2007', end='12/01/2021',freq='1M')
```

When I check the dimension with this code:

```
print(len(ENSO))
print(len(Waktu))
print(len(IOD))
```

It says:

```
180
179
180
```

How do I make the dimension of `date_range` 180?

Here is the screenshot of the excel data I use:

[image]

Comment: this looks like a relatively easy question to resolve. Please post sufficient code to reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **periods** instead of **end**, to make sure, you will have as many points as you need:

```
date_range(start='01/01/2007', periods=180, freq='1M')
```

Also, I guess in your case there is a problem that between '01/01/2007' and '12/01/2021' only 179 months. And when you use freq '**M**', it will provide only the end of the months. So if you want to get begin of the month you should use this:

```
date_range(start='01/01/2007', periods=180, freq=pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))
```